# Filling Null Spots in CSV in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am parsing a csv file to create charts. I am able to do this with no problem, EXCEPT in a single case... Whenever there is a null slot in the csv file. For example:

> Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
>     45   34      23     98     18
>     66            25     0
>     18            52     56    100

There are two blank entries in the file in column 2 and 5. I want to fill these spots with 0. I'm fairly new to Python. In the case where there is a null spot in the csv, I would like to insert a 0. Because I may sometimes have blanks in my csv file, I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'`. It can be tiresome to have to go into the csv file to check whether there is a null spot and manually fill it with zero so I would like a way to do this in the script. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


file_name = "myfile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
names = df['name'].values

x = np.arange(len(names))*2
w = 0.40

col2 = df.columns[1]
col3 = df.columns[2]
col4 = df.columns[3]
col5 = df.columns[4]

dif = df[col4] - df[col3]

colors = ['Red' if d < -5 else 'Blue' for d in dif]

plt.bar(x-w, df[col2].values, width=w*0.7, label=col2, color = "cyan")
plt.bar(x, df[col3].values, width=w*0.7, label=col3, color = "green")
plt.bar(x+w, df[col4].values, width=w*0.7, label=col4, color = colors)
plt.plot(x, df[col5].values, lw=2, label="Goal", color = "red")

plt.xticks(x, names, rotation='vertical')
plt.ylim([0,100])

plt.show()
```

Note: As I mentioned above, I'm reading the dataframe from a csv file.

EDIT:

I have added this line to my code:

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', 0, regex=True)
#For testing purposes, I also added this:
print(df.replace(r'^\s*$', 0, regex=True))
```

I can see that the empty slots are now filled with zeros but I am still getting the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'` for `dif = df[col4] - df[col3]`. Is it possibly reading those inserted 0 as strings?
I have also tried to wrap `df[col3]` and `df[col4]` in `int()` but no luck there. It gives the error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`. I then tried `df[col4].astype(int) - df[col3].astype(int)` and got the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

EDIT 2: 
I just added the line `print(df.dtypes)`. For some reason the fourth column (which was containing the replaced 0 in this case) is being seen as an object instead of int64 like the rest of the columns.

Comment: Fillna is your friend: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `replace` method provided by Pandas library.

This is the documentation: [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

In your case you would use

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', 0, regex=True)
```

Comment: I have modified. I was confused!

Comment: I am still getting the error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` where it is trying to do the subtraction operation on two empty slots.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import pandas as pd
   file_name = "myfile.csv"
   df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
   # a Pandas method that fills any NaN value with 0, you can change 0 to any value you 
   # want, you can use mean or median, etc
   df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```