# Convert an object from a parsed csv to int Python

Tags: python, pandas, types

This branches off my previous question - [Filling Null Spots in CSV in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495149/filling-null-spots-in-csv-in-python). I am making this a new question as I feel the issues I have encountered have entirely changed my question.

I want to convert the data in a column of type object to int as the values are integers.

After filling the empty slots in the columns, I am still having errors. I find that the fourth column in my csv file is being treated as an object instead of int instead of all the other columns. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


file_name = "myfile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df.replace(r'^\s*$', 0, regex=True)
names = df['name'].values

x = np.arange(len(names))*2
w = 0.40

col2 = df.columns[1]
col3 = df.columns[2]
col4 = df.columns[3]
col5 = df.columns[4]

print(df.dtypes)
df[col4] = df[col4].astype(str).astype(int)

dif = df[col4] - df[col3]

colors = ['Red' if d < -5 else 'Blue' for d in dif]

plt.bar(x-w, df[col2].values, width=w*0.7, label=col2, color = "cyan")
plt.bar(x, df[col3].values, width=w*0.7, label=col3, color = "green")
plt.bar(x+w, df[col4].values, width=w*0.7, label=col4, color = colors)
plt.plot(x, df[col5].values, lw=2, label="Goal", color = "red")

plt.xticks(x, names, rotation='vertical')
plt.ylim([0,100])

plt.show()
```

My approach to convert the 4th object column to int like the rest was by appending the astype as a string and then as an int to the end of it as shown in my code. I also tried just appending astype int however that did not work either. Here is the current error I am getting: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Please see my other post that I linked above for all details to how I got here in case you feel it will be helpful.

EDIT 1: Per comment request, here is an example of csv snippet before the code does the `df.replace()`.

> Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
>     45   34      23     98     18
>     66     0     25    
>     18     0      52     56    100

Here is the csv after:

> Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
>     45   34      23     98     18
>     66     0     25     0        0
>     18     0    52     56    100

Comment: Post csv code snippet you discuss in your parent question and version (if applicable). (End of Review).

Comment: @ZF007 I've updated the post as you requested. If you mean the python version, I am using 3.8.

Comment: You've added the csv in table format... I need actual codelines with comma separated value... I don't have excel or something to recreate it. Also, csv has sometimes obscure code hidden in the file that can be seen when you open such file (or sometimes not requiring different program to check). Clipping it out your question shows me `> Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5  
&nbsp; 45&nbsp; &nbsp;34`

Comment: @sfr you have `names = df['name'].values` in your code example but the column `ame` is not in your sample data

Comment: @ZF007 there is no problem with the example data. Just copy it to your clipboard and `df=pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: Just posted how to replace 'NaN' with zero. It can be any integer or float tbh. In case just one column you should use for example df['Col4'].fillna(0, inplace=True).

Comment: @Chris it's just an example. there is an actual column with that name. I just used col1, col2, etc... for the sake of showing how the csv looks.

Comment: @sfr is it possible to include the sample data as it is represented in a text editor with the comma delimiter?

Comment: What kind of CSV is that? Is it actually tab-separated, by any chance? (You cannot accurately paste tabs into SO posts because they get replaced by spaces.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of doing this without replace:

*Note: This might be expensive as this solution reshapes the dataframe.*

**Step1:** Creating the dataframe:

```
s="""
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
45,34,23,98,18
66, ,25, 
18, ,52,56,100
"""
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4   Col5
0    45   34    23   98   18.0
1    66         25         NaN
2    18         52   56  100.0
```

---

**Proposed Solution:**

From here *if you know that all your columns have numeric values* , you can make use of the **[`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)** function, with the `errors` param set to `coerce`.
From docs, we can see the coerce parses the invalid numeric entries to `NaN`:

> `If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN`

---

From here we can **[`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)** the dataframe as a series on which we apply `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and **[`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)** back to get the original shape like below:

```
s=df.stack(dropna=False)
final=pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce').fillna(0).unstack()
print(final)
```

---

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   Col5
0  45.0  34.0  23.0  98.0   18.0
1  66.0   0.0  25.0   0.0    0.0
2  18.0   0.0  52.0  56.0  100.0
```

If you want to save the original `NaN` i.e not replace them with 0, don't pass the `dropna` param in `df.stack()` as proposed above.

```
s=df.stack()
final=pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce').fillna(0).unstack()
print(final)
```

---

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   Col5
0  45.0  34.0  23.0  98.0   18.0
1  66.0   0.0  25.0   0.0    NaN
2  18.0   0.0  52.0  56.0  100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Chris in his comment I've used the `df=pd.read_clipboard()`.

```
... snippet ...
#df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df.replace(r'^\s*$', 0, regex=True)

print (df)

print (df['Col1'].values)
```

The print statement give the following result if the 'name' is changed in Column-n-name:

```
>>>    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   Col5
>>> 0    45    34    23  98.0   18.0
>>> 1    66     0    25   NaN    NaN
>>> 2    18     0    52  56.0  100.0

>>> [45 66 18]
```

To replace 'NaN' perform:

`df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` on the df. # applies it to all Columns at once.

So in case of all 'NaN' to be changed the result looks like:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   Col5
0    45    34    23  98.0   18.0
1    66     0    25   0.0    0.0
2    18     0    52  56.0  100.0
```

For column4: `df['Col4'].fillna(0, inplace=True)`

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   Col5
0    45    34    23  98.0   18.0
1    66     0    25   0.0    NaN
2    18     0    52  56.0  100.0
```

The `print (df['Col4'].values)` result:

`>>> [98.  0. 56.]`

I've also saved csv from the clippboarded table with/without fillna option. The csv output looks like below using `df.to_csv('blabla1', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')`:

Before `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`:

```
,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
0,45,34,23,98.0,18.0
1,66,0,25,,
2,18,0,52,56.0,100.0
```

After `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`:

```
,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
0,45,34,23,98.0,18.0
1,66,0,25,0.0,
2,18,0,52,56.0,100.0
```

Comment: I've tried this method previously but it does not work for some reason. It doesn't fill any of the slots with 0. That is why I use the replace function as in my code.

Comment: In your code `df[col4] = df[col4].astype(str).astype(int)` throws an ***ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '98.0'*** error. Did you see that?

Comment: Turning off the df.replace() doesn't change anything in the table visually.

Comment: So I did a print on the column and the data is being printed with apostrophes before and after like ['        93' '        78' '        85' '        98' '        91'
 '        96' '        77' '        50' '        99' '       100'
 '        87' '        94' '        88' '        96' '        86'
 '        87' '        90' '       100' '        78' '        83'
 '        46' '       100' 0 '        12' '        58' '        72'
 '        90' '        95' '        45' '        95' '        89'
 '       100' '        90' '        90']

Comment: I don't get the "" around the values. After having saved your example table to csv file and using that as file-input... everything works fine. I get a nice column graph (7 bars) with a nice V shape red line. My suggestion is to look at how your data in the csv file is being stored. Its not your code you wrote here at the question. (Also error on `df[col4] = df[col4].astype(str).astype(int)` is gone). Version: python=3.7.4, pandas=0.25.1, numpy=1.17.4, env: conda=4.8.0.

Comment: banging can be painfull.. but with help.. yes it helps a lot. Glad its fixed now ;-)